# MoveWindow function sometimes randomly moves window to wrong coordinates

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi, windows-10, user32

I have Winforms app that has foreign app embedded in it. I'm using SetParent function to set one of my panels as foreign window host.
`SetParent(hWndDocked, panelControl2.Handle)`

Everything works fine except when I move the main window guest window doesn't always move to desired position.
I am calling `MoveWindow(hWndDocked, xPos, yPos, width, height, true)` function in panel resize event. The goal is to show guest window in the center of parent panel.

I'm resizing the guest app window independently, so I don't want/need the `MoveWindow` to resize it.

When I try for example maximizing and restoring the main window repeatedly, guest window is sometimes positioned correctly and sometimes not.

When it doesn't reposition correctly guest window flickers for a second and I can see silhouette of correctly positioned guest window but then it goes back to incorrect position.

I will be very thankful for any advice.

Comment: [Is it legal to have a cross-process parent/child or owner/owned window relationship?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130412-00/?p=4683): "Yes, it is technically legal.

It is also technically legal to juggle chainsaws. ... they become near-impossible to manage if one or both of the windows involved is unaware that it is participating in a cross-process window tree."

Comment: *Everything works fine.* Extremely unlikely. This won't work out. Bail out now before you waste any more of your life on this fools errand.

Comment: Can you suggest any other way to achive my goal?

Comment: Wrap the embedded app into an ActiveX control. Hosting an out-of-process ActiveX control is a supported scenario. Btw., the flicker is really the least of your issues. The apps will lock up, at some point, and this is guaranteed to happen.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, i will have a look at it. What i tried to say when i mentioned the flicker was that it looks like embedded window moves as i want it to but then it goes back.

Comment: Don't worry. The flicker will end, once both processes have deadlocked.